# R : Rsofia convert sparse.model.matrix to SVM-light format

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, svmlight

I have a data set of ~ 25kR x 10C.  Several of the columns contain large numbers of levels in categorical variables.  I'm trying to convert the data set to SVM-Light format using the RSofia package but am getting the following error

```
Error in model.matrix.default(formula, data) : 
  allocMatrix: too many elements specified
```

I have successfully converted the data set to a `sparse.model.matrix` object using the `Matrix` package but am curious if it's possible to write an SVM-Light formatted file from a `sparse.model.matrix` object.

My code is below:

```
library(RSofia)
library(Matrix)

n = 100000
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:n, target = round(runif(n),0), col1 = factor(letters[sample(1:26,n,replace = T)])
        , col2 = factor(letters[sample(1:26,n,replace = T)])
        , col3 = round(runif(n)*1000,0)
        )
df1$col4 <- with(df1,factor(paste(col2, col3, sep = '')))
head(df1);length(unique(df1$col4))
str(df1)

varsToUse <- c('col1','col2','col3', 'col4')

smm1 <- sparse.model.matrix(df1$target ~ 0 +., data = df1[,varsToUse])
```

I get errors when I run this code:

```
x <- parse_formula(smm1$target ~ 0 +., data = smm1[,varsToUse])
x <- parse_formula(df1$target ~ 0 +., data = df1[,varsToUse])

tmp <- tempfile()
write.svmlight(x$labels, x$data, tmp);
readLines(tmp)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? I am looking at the same problem.

Comment: Sadly, no.  I think I have an idea of how to do it, but it will take a while to write the code.

Comment: I wrote a function to convert a data frame to svm-light format: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24143226/190791. Works for a binary classification. I am not sure if it helps here.